# Is it OK to boot multiple KVM guests from same OS image file?

Tags: kvm, qemu

Say I download an Ubuntu cloud image such as http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img

I can boot this up using qemu/kvm

Is it a "bad thing" to boot additional guests using exactly the same image file?

What problems will arise?

Presumably this is something that one should just not do, and instead should run each guest from its own Ubuntu cloud image file.  Is this correct?

Comment: you can while you edit setup of   VM to change mac@ ip@ hostnames etc...       of course ...

Comment: If the image is used RW, massive file system corruption on the image is what would happen.  you'd have several linux kernels all assuming they have exclusive and complete control over the filesystem, and all writing to it.  None of them know what the other kernels are writing, so have no way of knowing which blocks are free, and which are in use.    Clone the image before running it with multiple VMs - this is why filesystems etc with snap-shotting and/or cloning capability (e.g. LVM, qcow2, btrfs, zfs, etc) are commonly used in VM hosting environments.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to run multiple qemu's simultaneously on the same disk image, and assuming that the disk image is not setup to be read-only, then no, in general it will not work.  If the image is setup to boot read-only, such as a live image, then it should work although I haven't tried it.  You could test easily by setting it as read-only and trying it.